# jQuery: get element in parent document from iframe by data attribute

Tags: jquery, iframe, window, parent

I found some weird stuff, maybe there is a work around?

I have a selector: `[data-pcId=1369592034]`

```
// alerts 1, it finds the carousel in the parent document which
//has the attribute: data-pcId="1369592034"
alert($('.carousel', window.parent.document).length);

// alerts 0, so not found
alert($(selector, window.parent.document).length);
```

When I type `$(selector, window.parent.document)` or `$(selector)` in Firebug it **does** find the element, of course both queries are actually doing the same, because it checks the element outside the `iframe` and then `window.parent.document` is the same as `document`

Comment: And the question is ?

Comment: [**works for me**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/JFFtN/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the selector needs quotes.... [data-pcId="1369592034"]. Still weird it works without them in Firebug

Answer (score 0):

It won't work if the windows are of different domains (security). Otherwise it will. See the second comment by Dr. Molle.

Comment: I found out the selector needs quotes.... [data-pcId="1369592034"]. Still weird it works without them in Firebug